# Dynamic component selection in Vue-Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, dynamic-import, dynamic-components

I have a base component that is extended by some other Components as follows:

```html
// UserForm
<template>
    <div class="user-form"></div>
</template>

// AdministratorForm
<template>
    <UserForm v-model="administrator">
        // additional fields
    </UserForm>
</template>
```

Now I want to set up a dynamic route where the component is selected by a parameter:

```json
{
   path: '/users/:userTyp/:programId',
   name: 'user-create',
   component: () => import('@/modules/users/forms/'+ userTyp+ 'FormPage.vue'),
   props: (route: any) => ({
       programId: route.params.programId
   })
}
```

Is there any way to have that dynamic routing and when, and how?

I use the following versions:

- "vue": "^2.6.11",
- "vue-router": "^3.2.0"

Comment: You can grab the router prams userType and load you components dynamically using v-is attribute. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#ad

Comment: can you pleace give me an example? The aim is to add a new inherited component withoud need to add is anywhere (in routes or any other component)

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to load AdminStratorForm or other similar components based on the userType?

Comment: yes. depending on the userType the respective component should be loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to import the components in the router definition, you can dynamically import the components in Vue files. One way is using [:is attribute](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html#basic-usage) but it still contains unnecessary import of components. The better approach could be to [use dynamic imports from Webpack](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234) with the computed property.

What you can do is, give a component to your route-

```
{
   path: '/users/:userTyp/:programId',
   name: 'user-create',
   component: () => import('@/modules/SomeComponent.vue'),
}
```

And in that `SomeComponent.vue`, you can import the components dynamically based on the route params-

```
<template>
  <component v-bind:is="myComponent"></component>
</tamplarte>
```

```
computed: {
  myComponent() {
    let data = this.$route.params.userTyp;
    return () => import(`@/modules/users/forms/${data}/FormPage.vue`);
  }
},
```

Hope it helps.