# vue-router: provide different view, for same path, based on condition

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

We are looking to have a given path display different views depending on whether a user is authenticated, using `vue-router`

Two approaches I am looking at, but I am not sure how to make work at this point:

- In the `component()` function return one of the two views, though function takes no arguments, so I am not sure how to get the environment context
- Have two matching routes, with the first one having the second one as fallback, using logic added to `router.beforeEach()`

For the first approach:

```js
  {
    path: '/mypath/',
    component: () => {
      if (condition) {
       import('src/pages/offers/PublicContent.vue');
      } else {
       import('src/pages/offers/PrivateContent.vue');
      }
    }
  }
```

For the second approach:

```js
  {
    path: '/mypath/',
    component: () => {
      import('src/pages/offers/PrivateContent.vue');
    },
    meta: {
     requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/mypath/',
    component: () => {
      import('src/pages/offers/PublicContent.vue');
    }
  }
```

For the second approach I would think the `router.beforeEach()` would need to act as if the route didn't match, but I am not sure how to do that in a way that `vue-router` tries an alternative route match?

Comment: third idea would be to just import both components, and [conditionally render](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html) them based on the authentication state

Comment: Can you present the suggestion as an answer, with an example, since this seems to be coding things at the component level, rather than in the routing logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting I went with the second of the options, using a duplicate path and naming them. The logic in the `beforeEach()` handler was able to do the necessary magic.

The routes:

```js
  {
    name: 'PrivateContent',
    path: '/mypath/',
    component: () => {
      import('src/pages/offers/PrivateContent.vue');
    },
    meta: {
     requiresAuth: true,
     publicAlt: 'PublicContent'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'PublicContent',
    path: '/mypath/',
    component: () => {
      import('src/pages/offers/PublicContent.vue');
    }
  }
```

The `beforeEach()`:

```js
  router.beforeEach(
    async (
      to: RouteLocationNormalized,
      _from: RouteLocationNormalizedLoaded,
      next: (route?: { name: string } | string) => void
    ) => {
      // if authentication is not required then just display
      if (!isAuthRequired(to)) {
        next();
        return;
      }

      // handle private pages with public variants
      if (isAuthRequired(to) && !isAuthenticated() && publicFallback(to)) {
        if (to.meta && to.meta.publicAlt) {
          next({ name: to.meta.publicAlt as string });
        } else {
          next({ name: 'Error404' });
        }
        return;
      }
    }
  );
```

So here, if the page requires authentication, but were are not logged in and there is a public alternative for it, then redirect to it, otherwise display the 404 page. We could have displayed a 503, but 404 matches our design requirements.

Comment: Not sure but Isn't this a very lengthy approach? If you consider @yoduh's comment, it would be much shorter and easier. What say?

Comment: Without seeing their suggestion as an answer, I can't say.

Comment: As I agree with @youduh's comment, I guess he meant, to create a common component, let's say, `Common.vue`, and render this component on your `/mypath` route. Inside the `Common` component, dynamic import the `Private` and `Public` component as per auth condition and render them in the template by using the component `:is` directive. You can see the dynamic import in this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75541968/11834856. Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: This doesn't really work for us, since each of the pages aren't sharing the same parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is best practice.

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import WebLayout        from '@/components/layouts/Website.vue'
import Home             from "@/components/Home.vue";
import About            from "@/components/About.vue";
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: WebLayout,
    children: [
      { path: "/", name: "Home", component: Home },
      { path: "/about-us", name: "About", component: About }
    ]
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
   history: createWebHistory(),
   routes,
});
```

Comment: Best practice to do what? Not sure how this addresses the question?